# JavaScript Every() method returns false even though it is true?

Tags: javascript

I do not get it why false is returned, am I missing something here?

```
const validInputs = (...inputs) => {
  const check = inputs.every(inp => {
    Number.isFinite(inp);
  });
  return check;
};

console.log(validInputs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Your `every` callback never returns anything, which basically means it always returns `undefined`, which is falsy.

Comment: Watching a JS course and an instructor wrote the exact same code without returning anything in every callback, his code returns true,  and mine false, what should I return  explicitly though, true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues, the callback isn't returning anything and you shouldn't rest the array(`(...input)`) as this will make inputs an array of array.

```js
const validInputs = (inputs) => {
  const check = inputs.every(inp => {
    return Number.isFinite(inp);
  });
  return check;
};

console.log(validInputs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Ah I am watching a course, he wrote a callback without {} and totally forgot it includes return keyword automatically, also called a  function without  without [], thank you.